# ValueError: script 'filename.py' not found when using pyinstaller to edit a .spec file

Tags: python, pyinstaller

So i'm trying to change something in the .spec file which i've named "filename.py", although pyinstaller can never find the file even if i open the command prompt from within the folder that contains the file.
I've even tried inserting the whole file path but still received the same error.

```
PS C:\Users\S3401\Desktop\New folder> pyi-makespec filename.py
wrote C:\Users\S3401\Desktop\New folder\filename.spec
now run pyinstaller.py to build the executable
PS C:\Users\S3401\Desktop\New folder> pyinstaller .\filename.spec
46 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.3.1
46 INFO: Python: 3.6.6
46 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
47 INFO: UPX is not available.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.3.1', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 94, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 791, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 737, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 162, in __init__
    raise ValueError("script '%s' not found" % script)
ValueError: script 'filename.py' not found
```

Comment: Did you try using the absolute path ?

Comment: Yes i tried that but it did not work.